# Trying to pass data (bundle/extras) into a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, android-activity

This is what I am doing:

In a ListActivity (NOT a ListFragment):

```
Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyFragmentActivity.class);
i.putExtra("name", items.get(arg2));
startActivity(i);
```

Then in MyFragmentActivity (using support library):

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_layout);

    this.initialiseTabHost(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        mTabHost.setCurrentTabByTag(savedInstanceState.getString("tab"));

        RateFrag rate = new RateFrag();
        rate.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, rate).commit();

    }

    this.intialiseViewPager();
}
```

Then in Rate Fragment:

```
 public class RateFrag extends Fragment {

  public static RateFrag newInstance(CharSequence name) {
    RateFrag f = new RateFrag();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putCharSequence("name", name);
    f.setArguments(args);
    return f;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Item = getArguments().getString("name");

}



@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    title = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.tvRateItem);
    ratingsBar = (RatingBar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.theRatingBar);

    title.setText(Item);

}

 // stuff!

 }
```

So I am essentially trying to pass an "extra" from the original ListActivity into a textview in the Fragment in the last line of code above.

This is what I get in LogCat when I click on the ListItem:

```
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.---.---.RateFrag.onCreate(RateFrag.java:61)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:834)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.performPendingDeferredStart(FragmentManager.java:768)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setUserVisibleHint(Fragment.java:746)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.setPrimaryItem(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:128)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:802)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1016)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1390)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:681)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:833)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:574)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4814)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2148)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15172)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1848)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1100)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1273)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:998)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4212)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-09 19:12:39.998: E/AndroidRuntime(1788):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Converting my app to use Fragments is driving me nuts!  Admittedly, the final product is much better looking, its complexity is extremely frustrating.  Can someone point me in the right direction to see where I am failing?

EDIT:  Here is my Tab Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabHost
        android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            >

            <TabWidget
                android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="0"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+android:id/content"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TabHost>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It seems complicated at first, but the ability to use `Fragment`s as re-usable UI components makes your app much simpler, believe it or not.

Comment: I believe you.  Doesn't make it any less frustrating though!  Something that was basic like passing data through intents, seems to have added many more lines of code.

Comment: You shouldn't pass `getApplicationContext()` to the `new Intent()`... you should pass it `this` instead.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want to have your fragment manipulate the `Activity`'s views directly? Usually you don't want to do this... in almost all cases the `Fragment`'s should be independent of a specific parent `Activity`.

Comment: Here is my confusion: Using (http://thepseudocoder.wordpress.com/2011/10/05/android-page-swiping-using-viewpager) this tutorial, I want to set up TWO tabs with a Viewpager and one FragmentActivity to "control" both.  Now I am thinking I need one Activity per tab? I'm not sure and need to just study more on Fragments. If it is not ideal for a Fragment to manipulate the Activity's view, then what DOES a Fragment do? Just provides the layout for an Activity?

Comment: Yeah, in most cases `Fragment`s are meant to be "separate UI components". i.e. you want to design them so that you could potentially reuse them elsewhere w/o too much trouble. Of course, this doesn't mean that you can't have the `Fragment` report back to the `Activity` at all. The canonical example is w/ multipaned layouts when you want one fragment to change the view of another fragment... in these situations you would want the first fragment to report a callback event to the Activity, which would then pass the event to the second fragment.

Comment: In your situation, it sounds like the `TabHost` will treat the `Fragment`s as encapsulated objects... it doesn't know how they are implemented or what they do. All it knows is how to instantiate the `Fragment` and attach it to the tab's screen. In this case, the `Fragment`'s behavior should be mostly independent of the underlying `Activity`... like I said, it's behavior is encapsulated and it doesn't really need to know what created it or the context in which it is being displayed. Hopefully that makes some sense...

Comment: Last thing... it sounds like the problem is your initial setup... it sounds really weird to have a `ViewPager` within a single tab within an `Activity`. It's also kind of confusing from the user's point of view. Are you sure this is the best option?

Comment: Hey, thanks for you wealth of info!  What I am trying to do is create two tabs where a user can simply swipe back and forth.  The two tabs are related in info but not in anyway connected to each other. In the past, it was simply one Activity with a button on it that opened up to a ListActivity.  Now I am trying to modernize the layout and make it as fluid as possible for the user. (I just added the layout code up top taken directly from that blog so you can see the initial setup. Visually, I have it working exact as it should using the two former layouts the former Activities used.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are attempting to instantiate two `Fragment`'s here... one is being inflated from `fragment_layout.xml`, and the other is being instantiated programatically and placed on screen with a `FragmentTransaction`.

Pick *only one* of these two means of instantiating your `Fragment`... whichever option best suits the situation (I can't tell from the minimal code you have provided).

Comment: Well I am marking this correct because this explains the LogCat I was getting.  After deciding to NOT use the xml layout directly, I received a different LogCat error on some NullPointer.  So the probably isn't solved but I think I am doing this with a serious flawed technique and will just have to start from scratch again.